# Get value of custom attribute in Magento echo result based on number

Tags: php, magento, echo

I'm attempting to pull in custom attributes from Magento which is working fine. I'm then attempting to interpret the numeric value (0,1,2,3,4 or 5) into a custom star rating system using font awesome icons.

At the moment this is only echoing the number, but I'm unsure as to how to get it to display as an icon. For example

```
if value=='1'
```

then echo the

```
<span class="fa fa-star"></span>
```

This code is working to output the raw value of 0,1,2,3,4,5 - it's the conversion to a icon representation I'm unsure how to do

```
<?php     
    $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ts_visual_merit');
    if ($attribute) {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'ts_visual_merit', $storeId);
```

That will get you the raw value (1,2,3,4 or 5 in your case)

Comment: I have the value outputting already, it's the converting that value into the star icons that I can't work out